# Store comma separate values into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store comma separate values into array.
Later i want check it with different check.

```
var_str= name,address,state,city // I want make array from this variable
```

How could i do this...

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Assuming that you have a string and want to convert it to an array)Split method on strings splits strings on a separator.

```
var str = "name,address,state,city";
var arr = str.split(',');
```

Comment: hey you. you save my life ^_^

Answer (score 1):

if you have such string:

```
var _str= 'name,address,state,city';
```

to get array from string use split javascript function:

```
var arr = _str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're strings, jut give it array notation:

```
var str = [name,address,state,city];
```

in this array `str[0]` would be name, etc.  If they're *not* string's variables...I'm unsure what you're asking.

Comment: i want to make array from var_str variable to make array from this coz i want check it with different thing. (sorry i forgot var to declare variable)

Comment: @Joko - you have a comma separated string currently, or you have 4 strings you want to place in an array?

Comment: @nick - yes nick coz i want to do loop check of it. These variables is sent from PHP ( I use $.ajax method )

Comment: @Joko - you answered yes to an **or** question...?

Comment: @Joko - in that case the above code works, it'll stick 4 variables into an array...