# How to convert string separated by commas to array?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)
>   [Store comma separate values into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526459/store-comma-separate-values-into-array)

I have a string containing values separated with commas:

```
"1,4,5,11,58,96"
```

How could I turn it into an object? I need something like this

```
["1","4","5","11","58","96"]
```

Comment: I didn't find any information about it in Google...

Comment: JSON is *a textual serialization of data*. I have updated the question to reflect needing a *JavaScript array*. If you need the JSON *text representation* of this array, that is an additional step (and is achieved as shown in joeltine's answer). Update or clarify the question as needed. Also, remember to "accept" answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will convert it into an array (which is the JSON representation you specified):

```
var array = myString.split(',');
```

If you need the string version:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Comment: be aware that `JSON.stringify` is not in IE6 or 7.

Comment: it worked only with end_value=JSON.stringify(start_value); [probably because start_value was parsed from json]. thank you very much :)

Comment: wouldn't the string version be `var string = array.join(',');`

Answer (score 3):

In JSON, numbers don't need double quotes, so you could just append `[` and `]` to either end of the string, resulting in the string `"[1,4,5,11,58,96]"` and you will have a JSON Array of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

make it an array

```
var array = myString.split(',');
```